# $x\mapsto a\,x$ is an unbounded function yet a bounded functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the linear function $f(x):=ax$ for some fixed $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is a continuous function that is linear and unbounded.

If we look at $f$ as a real functional on the real normed space $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$ then $f$ is clearly a linear functional. And we do have

$$|f(x)|=|a||x|,\qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

which shows $f$ is a bounded functional.

In fact the same thing applies to linear functions $f(x):=Ax$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A\in M_{n\times n}$, in higher dimensions.

Am I missing something or is it true that the concept of boundedness of the this $f$ does depend on the context (viewing it as a function as opposed to as a functional ) ?

Comment: You're not missing anything. This is just an example where the same word "bounded" has different, conflicting meanings in different contexts. Sometimes the same word gets re-used for different purposes.

Comment: Remark: The only linear maps on normed $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ vector spaces which are bounded (in the sense that they have bounded range) are the zero maps. The only way to find other linear maps with bounded range is to change what "boundedness of a set" means.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, boundedness means different things in these two different contexts.

For a function $f \mathpunct{:} \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ boundedness means that the range of $f$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

However, for a normed vector space $X$, a bounded linear functional $f \mathpunct{:} X \to\mathbb{R}$ is one that maps bounded sets in $X$ to bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Whilst this justifies the use of the word boundedness in each case, it is somewhat unfortunate that the word is used with conflicting meanings in these two contexts. However it is usually clear from context in which way it is meant.